# How to make hour, minute offset flags in C programming

Tags: c, unix, datetimeoffset

I am using C on Unix. The program displays the time and I am trying to figure out how to offset the current time in minutes and hours.

This part of the code

```
  while ( ( let = getopt(argc, argv, "alo:vh")) != -1 ) {
    switch (let) {
    case 'o':  offset = atoi(optarg);  break; }
```

and later in this part:

```
void clock(int sig, int time_expires)
{
time_t       now;
struct tm   *dateinfo; 

(void) time(&now);
now = now + offset;

dateinfo = localtime( &now ); }
```

Makes an -o offset, which offsets the current time by a certain amount of seconds. For example, -o590 would offset the current time by 590 seconds.

I am trying to figure out how to do this same thing only with an -h flag that offsets the time by a certain amount of hours (like -h6 offsets the time by 6 hours) or by a -m flag which offsets the time by minutes.

I have tried dividing the current -o flag by 60 or 360 but that is not working. Can anyone point me in the right directions here?

Comment: "I have tried dividing the current -o flag by 60 or 360 but that is not working". Please be more specific. Show the exact code you have tried and describe in what way it is "not working".

Comment: The default ofset is in seconds. Why divide? You should be multiplying by 60 for minutes and 3600 for hour. So `-m1` is actually equivalent to `-o60` and `-h1` is `-o3600`.

Answer (score 1):

To change `time_t` by so many hours, minutes, seconds in a *portable* fashion *without* relying on `time_t` is some integer type of seconds since 1970, use `mktime()`

```
time_t adjust(time_t t, int hour, int minute, int second) {
  struct tm *dateinfo; 
  dateinfo = localtime(&t);
  if (dateinfo == NULL) return (time_t) -1;
  dateinfo->tm_hour += hour;
  dateinfo->tm_min += minute;
  dateinfo->tm_sec += second;
  return mktime(dateinfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `time_t` structure defines the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC.

If you want to add n minutes you should do:

```
now+= n*60
```

And for n hours you should:

```
now+= n*3600
```

Alternatively you can use `struct tm` and access directly to the time quanta you wish  to modify.

```
struct tm {
   int tm_sec;         /* seconds,  range 0 to 59          */
   int tm_min;         /* minutes, range 0 to 59           */
   int tm_hour;        /* hours, range 0 to 23             */
   int tm_mday;        /* day of the month, range 1 to 31  */
   int tm_mon;         /* month, range 0 to 11             */
   int tm_year;        /* The number of years since 1900   */
   int tm_wday;        /* day of the week, range 0 to 6    */
   int tm_yday;        /* day in the year, range 0 to 365  */
   int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time             */
};
```